# Angular service: should I expose the actual data or should I wrap it with an observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In Angular (currently 6), should I have a service that exposes a list of objects, or should I wrap this list with an observable?

this is how i expose a simple list of objects:

```
export class TicketService {

  private _tickets: List<Ticket>;

  constructor() { }

  init() {
    this.backend.getTickets().subscribe(tickets => this._tickets = tickets);
  }

  getTickets() {
    return this._tickets;
  }
}
```

this seems very straightforward, this is also how I did it with angularjs 1.x. the components that display the data point to the same object as the service, so any change in the object done in the service, will automatically show in the view layer.

is this still an accepted pattern in Angular, or I need to use Observables as described here: https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/

will the first method work? what are the advantages of the seconds method?

Comment: The first method will work, but only if the async `getTickets()` has returned. Because it's async, there is no guarantee that `_tickets` will have been set, which is why we use Observables. Typically, you would return `this.backend.getTickets()`

Comment: Yes, I often see the pattern using simple objects. You just need to ensure you check for the resulting property. One way to accomplish that is to use a getter in the component. Option 2 as you stated is to use a Subject/BehaviorSubject. A third option that is gaining popularity is to use NgRx. It is a state management library that manages your list of objects and provides notifications.

Comment: You are actually using Observables as well as a Service. You are using Observables since you are subscribing to `this.backend.getTickets()` which is likely to return an Observable. You are using a Service since `this.backend` sounds just like a service injected via Dependency Injection.

Comment: I'd agree with Deborah's opinion and personally prefer Subjects/BehaviorSubjects as you can return them as Observable and subscribe to them inside your component. So you'll always get an update if `_tickets` changes.

Comment: :-) Personally, I'm getting pretty hooked on NgRx. Love that visual state/action operation/debugging tool!

Answer (score 0):

Here you are basically making an HTTP request and caching the result.

Anything can now access that result. Great but a few problems:

(1) What happens if the HTTP request failed.

(2) If the tickets have changed at the backend, how do I request the updated tickets?

(3) Components subscribing to an RxJS Subject based service - see https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service - which could very easily incorporate an HTTP request, get auto-notified of data changes without having to request data from a service. It's identical to the HTTP polling v websockets paradigm but at a component level instead. In the former the client makes regular requests of the server checking to see if the data has changed (inefficient coz requests may be made when no data has changed and changes are not received immediately but only when the client asks), in the latter the server tells the client the data has changed and gives the new data to the client (perfection, total efficiency and immediate change notification).

If you can guarantee the HTTP request will never fail AND the data never changes then your approach is fine. Else I would re-think it.

TIP: Advanced - Components subscribing to an RxJS subject will only receive the new data if they are subscribed at the time that the new data is emitted. Where this is not the case, consider using an RxJS Replay Subject or even better still a global store solution such as ngrx.

PS: No need to wrap anything, this.backend.getTickets() is an Observable